# Error in loading a DLL

Tags: c, release, package

I packed my VC application in release mode and tested in a clean Windows XP/2003. Once I run the application, it could not load my dll and reports the system error code 14001, which is 'ERROR_SXS_CANT_GEN_ACTCTX'. The api which returns the error is LoadLibrary

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in side-by-side assemblies, clean Windows XP didn't have necessary assemblies, I think VC80.CRT or VC90.CRT (most probably). See about side-by side assemblies [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd408052%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You have 2 options to solve this issue: deploy assemblies with your application or build your application with static CRT libraries using /MT flag.